# Trouble assigning optarg when using getopt()

Tags: c

I am having trouble assigning optarg to a `inFilename` and `outFilename`. The error states that an incompatible type error has occurred. Please forgive me if this a trivial error, I've started learning C about a week ago.

EDIT: I've used strncpy but getting segmentation fault.

EDIT: Here is how I plan on using this :

./sortfile -i input.txt -o output.txt

```
     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char c;

        const int MAX_FILENAME_LEN = 256;
        const int MAX_NUMBERS      = 100;

        int xFlag = 0;
        int yFlag = 0;

        char inFilename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
        char outFilename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
        int  *numbers;  // number array: to be dynamically allocated
        int  count;
        int  exitValue = 1;

        //printf("Enter the input file name: ");
        //scanf("%s", inFilename);

        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "ioxy")) != -1) {
                switch (c) {
                        case 'i':
                                strncpy(inFilename, optarg, sizeof(inFilename) - 1);
                                break;
                        case 'o':
                                strncpy(outFilename, optarg, sizeof(outFilename) - 1);
                                break;
                        case 'x':
                                xFlag = 1;
                                break;
                        case 'y':
                                yFlag = 1;
                                break;
                        case '?':
                                fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized option!\n");
                                break;
                }
        }

        if (!inFilename || !outFilename) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Must have -i and -o option!\n");
                exit(0);
        }


        numbers = (int *) malloc(MAX_NUMBERS * sizeof(int)); 

        count = readNumbers(numbers, inFilename);

        if (count >= 0) {
                //printf("Enter the output file name (will be created/overwitten): ");
                //scanf("%s", outFilename);

                printArray(numbers, count);
                bubbleSort(numbers, count, true);

                printArray(numbers, count);
                writeNumbers(numbers, count, outFilename);
       }

        free(numbers);

        return exitValue;
}
```

Here is the program before the changes. This program works.

```
int main(void) {
const int MAX_FILENAME_LEN = 256;
const int MAX_NUMBERS      = 100;

char inFilename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
char outFilename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
int  *numbers;  // number array: to be dynamically allocated
int  count;
int  exitValue = 1;

printf("Enter the input file name: ");
scanf("%s", inFilename);


numbers = (int *) malloc(MAX_NUMBERS * sizeof(int)); 

count = readNumbers(numbers, inFilename);

if (count >= 0) {
    printf("Enter the output file name (will be created/overwitten): ");
    scanf("%s", outFilename);

    printArray(numbers, count);
    bubbleSort(numbers, count, true);

    printArray(numbers, count);
    writeNumbers(numbers, count, outFilename);

    exitValue = 0;
}


free(numbers);

return exitValue;
```

}

Comment: `c` isn't defined here

Comment: @self Oh sorry, c is defined but since my main method is very long, I've only posted the relevant parts. I can post the entire thing if needed.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays like that in C, you have to use `strcpy()` or friends.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Hello, I've used strncpy now however I am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: You need to show a short, but complete compilable program, then. You can rewrite it to only take in one option, copy the name, and do nothing else, for instance.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I've stepped through using GDB and segmentation fault occurs at strncpy. So I know that is the problematic area.

Comment: @Renren29: Since this is dealing with command line arguments, can you show how you're running it, also, i.e. what you're typing at the command line to execute it.

Comment: Also, you didn't provide a compilable example. There are calls to `printArray()` and `bubbleSort()` and all sorts of things that you didn't provide. Your `#include`s are missing, too. Can you remove everything except for the minimum required to demonstrate your problem? You dramatically reduce the ability of anyone to help you if you don't give them code they can compile and run.

Comment: That's misusing `strncpy()` (you don't guarantee null termination of the strings), and you don't need to use `strcpy()` or `strdup()` either; you can simply use `char *inFileName; char *outFileName;` and assign `inFileName = optarg;` and`outFileName = optarg;` without dangers of overflow, etc.

Comment: Most obviously, though, `getopt(argc, argv, "ioxy")` tells `getopt` that none of your four options take arguments, which will be why attempts to copy them out of `optarg` are failing.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths YESSSSS !!!! Thank you!!! I've added ":" and it works!!! I've stepped through with GDB a million times and pulled 30% of my hair off. I'm so dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
getopt(argc, argv, "ioxy")
```

tells `getopt()` about four options, `i`, `o`, `x` and `y`, none of which take arguments. This is why any attempts to get those arguments from `optarg` are failing, because they aren't there.

What you need is:

```
getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:xy")
```

to tell `getopt()` that your `i` and `o` options should have arguments